# Плагин для IDE Gogland Remote Hosts Access

Tags: ssh, ide, плагин, развертывание

После установки последней версии перестал работать плагин для удаленной выгрузки на сервер проекта из среды.

Среду переустановил, проблема остается. Пишет, что плагин не скачан потому что нет другого плагина. Пытался найти этот плагин, не нашел.

Подскажите как восстановить работу плагина, либо подскажите альтернативные варианты выгрузки проект на удаленный сервер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887654/plugin-remote-hosts-access-for-gogland) полученному на английском SO.
Разработчики знают об этой [проблеме](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4681) и исправят в ближайшем релизе EAP 17.